# How to re-execute a function in a certain interval?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and it needs to run a function in a fixed period of time so it can work with dynamic pages.

I have used `setInterval` but it only executed the function once, and if it were modified to the following:

```
function sumfunc(){
    document.body.innerHTML = dosumthin(document.body.innerHTML,false);
    setInterval(sumfunc(),1000);
}
```

It would lag the page while filling the call stack and making it seem like the page never finishes loading.

Comment: The problem is using `sumfunc()` instead of `sumfunc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `()`:

```
setTimeout(sumfunc,1000);
```

---

`setTimeout()`'s first argument takes a function definition, not an execution of one.

As your executing `sumfunc` inside `sumfunc`, this will cause immediate infinite recursion, which will potentially cause a stack overflow, as you have described.

---

Therefore replace your code with the following:

```
function sumfunc(){
    document.body.innerHTML = dosumthin(document.body.innerHTML,false);
    setTimeout(sumfunc,1000);
}
```

Comment: Amazing how you are the only one that mentioned the real problem. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setInterval` instead:

```
function sumfunc(){
 document.body.innerHTML = dosumthin(document.body.innerHTML,false);
}
window.setInterval(sumfunc,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The page lags because every time the timout starts it will call the timeout again. You have to set the timeout outside of the function like this:

```
setInterval(sumfunc,1000);
function sumfunc(){
    document.body.innerHTML = dosumthin(document.body.innerHTML,false);
}
```

Comment: But if i add outside it will run the function only once

Comment: Oh sorry, then you have to use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You need an interval rather than a timeout.

```
function sumfunc(){
    document.body.innerHTML = dosumthin(document.body.innerHTML,false);
}

setInterval(sumfunc, 1000);
```